# ASP.NET MVC4 displaying all registered Users name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a problem programming  with  c#, html, using razor, in displaying all registered members name , from the default database UserProfile, i need to display UserName

```
    public UsersContext()  : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<UserProfile> GetAll(string _UserName)
    {
        IQueryable<UserProfile> query = this.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.UserName==_UserName);
        return query;
    }
```

and in the model

```
       using (UsersContext _UsersContext = new UsersContext())
        {
            this.RegisterMembers = _UsersContext.UserProfiles.ToString();
        }
```

in the view

#### Registerd members : @Model.RegisterMembers.ToString()

I am trying my best for 3 days now, and it wont work with all ways! Help plz and THANK YOU!!!

Comment: what you trying to get? if you want All list then why you writing FirstOrDefault.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you are calling `ToString` against `DbSet<UserProfile>` which won't return what you expect. As a starting point you can display it as a CSV:

```
this.RegisterMembers = String.Join(",", _UsersContext.UserProfiles.Select(x => x.UserName).ToList());
```

If you not happy with that you need to change type of `RegisterMembers` to `List<UserProfile>` and in action you need to assign that list like:

```
this.RegisterMembers = _UsersContext.UserProfiles.ToList();
```

So it your view you will be able to iterate through `RegisterMembers` like so:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var registerMember in Model.RegisterMembers)
{
    <li>@registerMember.UserName</li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: @MissAwesome you're welcome. Also suggest to go through any asp.net mvc tutorial (e.g. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3) as it seems like you are missing some basics.

Answer (score 1):

You method

```
public IQueryable<UserProfile> GetAll(string _UserName)
{
    IQueryable<UserProfile> query = this.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.UserName==_UserName);
    return query;
}
```

Will only return ONE UserProfile, you shouldn't take any argument and just call something like this:

```
IQueryable<UserProfile> query = this.UserProfiles.ToArray();
```

Comment: I think it clearly that issue is not with method you mentioned and it is not used in that example at all.